# Value of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k k (k+1)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to compute this value, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\int_{0}^{0.5}\int_{0}^{x}y^{k-1}dy =\frac{{0.5}^{k+1}}{k(k+1)}= $. Also, you can interchange the integration and summation.